# Getting data from an angularjs component in the script tag in the template.html file

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

The component file gets data from a csv file and it has a templateUrl to another html file. This html file contains a script tag in which some functionality takes place. I want to access the array from the response.data in the component file in the script tag in the HTML file.

```
angular.module("keyMetric",[])
.component("keyMetric",{
    templateUrl : 'keymetric/keymetric.template.html',
    controller : function control($http) {
        $http.get('customers.csv').then(function(response){
            var arr = response.data;
            var arrsplit = arr.split(',');
        });
    }
});
```

I want to access the arrsplit variable in the script tag in the keymetric.template.html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$rootScope`.

```
$http.get('customers.csv').then(function(response){
            var arr = response.data;
            var arrsplit = arr.split(',');
            $rootScope.datareceived = arrsplit;
        });
```

Now in html

access like `{{$root.datareceived[0]}}` .

To access scope variable in script

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="controllername"]')).scope().yourscopevariable
```

or by using jquery

```
var whateveryouwant = $('[ng-controller="controllername"]').scope().yourscopevariable;
```

Here is a generic way to get hold of scope variable outside angular context

```
function getScope(ctrlName) {
    var sel = 'div[ng-controller="' + ctrlName + '"]';
    return angular.element(sel).scope();
}
```

This can be called by passing the controller name

```
var $scope = getScope('ctrl');
```

Comment: <script></script>

Comment: <script></script> I want to add it within the script tags, is it possible to use scope variables inside the script tag? I want to use it for JS functions